# Converting Time Delta '#hms' to datetime time delta?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a reservation system where a required field from the user is 'reservation time' of the from `#h#m#s` (Hours Minutes Seconds). where one or more option is required. Is there a way to convert this to time deltas nicely?

Right now my only approach is to use this regex `(\d*)h?(\d*)m?(\d*)s?`
Which gives me groups [1-3].

[image]

I then can translate this to

```
class MaxTimeField(pw.CharField):
    def db_value(self, value):
        times = re.search(TIME_DELTA, value)
        times = str(
            timedelta(
                **{
                    "hours": int(times.group(1) or 0),
                    "minutes": int(times.group(2) or 0),
                    "seconds": int(times.group(3) or 0),
                }
            )
        )
        return super().db_value(times)
```

...
If that group exists. I feel like there might be something out there that does this nicely but I can not find it. I would like to avoid using regex, if there might be a more elegant approach. I would love suggestions.

Comment: What's wrong with the technique you're using?

Comment: I was just hoping there was a more eloquent way, I really hate using regex if it can be avoided.

Comment: I think your general approach is fine, but you'll probably need to play with the regex a bit. Note that groups that don't contain all three of hours, minutes, and seconds probably don't give you the results you expect.

Comment: I am new to regex, I get blank strings for unmatched groups. I can work with this however.

Comment: @hobbs haha, fair. I will yield to the regex. Do you have any recommendations on how to clean up anything?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the technique you're using. Your code looks fine, but I suppose there's inevitably a few minor nits to explore.

Consider defining `time_re = re.compile(r'(\d*)h?(\d*)m?(\d*)s?')` outside the function, and referencing it with `time_re.search(value)`. The function is called many times, but the regex only needs to be compiled once.

Where you use `\d*` I probably would have gone with `\d+`, though the `or 0` expression suggests there may be trouble if fields are missing. I *am* worried about inputs like '9h24s'.

Consider unpacking with `h, m, s = times.groups()`, then constructing `dict(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)`. It's just another style, which avoids the 1,2,3 args.

Consider using a slightly more "busy" (or at least slightly longer) regex:

```
time_re = re.compile(r'(?P<hours>\d*)h?(?P<minutes>\d*)m?(?P<seconds>\d*)s?')
d = time_re.search(value).groupdict()
```

Each of the dictionary `d` values is a string at that point, so you'd still need to convert to integer, while coping with empty strings.

A list like `[('h', 3600), ('m', 60), ('s', 1)]` would let you abandon regex altogether, and accumulate total number of seconds. First element of each pair is `unit`. If `unit` is present in the string then `.split()` on it, convert to `int`, and accumulate the product.